# restoring vscode settings to default

Tags: visual-studio-code

In vscode, there is an option to chose which language I'm going to use when I make a new file. I accidentally clicked do not show for this setting/UI but I want it back. I tried googling it but I can't find any solutions. Is this is even changeable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about [this feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_56#_untitled-editors-hint), it can be re-enabled by changing the value of `Workbench > Editor > Untitled: Hint` (workbench.editor.untitled.hint) in the settings.
But without that feature you can still change language mode by clicking the button at the bottom right of the window.

[image]

Comment: thank you! you guessed the feature i was talking about spot on lol. thanks for the new tip too ! much appreciated